# I need a pathway for studying Lattice-Based Cryptography

Tags: public-key, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, practice

I realize that I need a study pathway for post-quantum cryptography.

I started to study post-quantum crypto by reading NIST PQC 3rd-round submissions of the lattice-based schemes (let's start with the most popular ones). I understood Kyber and Saber so that I could implement them. However, I want to understand the design rationales behind them. Why these errors have that length, what is the role of these parameters in practice.

Since the first lattice-based encryption schemes, there must be many improvements done considering speed or security. I need to understand these. Then, I started searching for papers about lattice-based algorithms and their attacks over the history of lattices. I found a large list [here](http://pqcrypto.org/lattice.html), but I could not filter these papers.

How should I start? Is there a good survey for me, or a list of readable papers covering the area?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Chris can give you a better answer when they see this Q, however, https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/74313/18298

Comment: also it may help to describe your mathematical background

Comment: I found chapter 6 of " An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography" book https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/MathCryptoHome.html and djb and Tanja's LatticeHacks https://latticehacks.cr.yp.to/index.html very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Katz and Lybushavesky *just* (yesterday) released [a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498763472) on lattice based cryptography. My particular copy is still shipping, so I can't mention whether it covers what you are in particular interested in, but as:

- Lyubashevesky is a co-author of both the KYBER and DILITHIUM finalists
- Katz's prior book (with Yehuda Lindell) *Introduction to Modern Cryptography* is widely praised for its excellent writing (and Katz is a co-author of the non-lattice Picnic round 3 alternate signature scheme)

It seems quite possible this could be the "goto" recommendation for learning lattice-based cryptography generically, and potentially even have exposition on the NIST candidates --- I won't know until my copy arrives though.

[These slides by Daniel Apon](https://www.scribd.com/document/474476570/PQC-Overview-Aug-2020-NIST) (at NIST) regarding why NIST made the particular round 3 selections may also be useful for discussing the "design space" of lattice-based NIST candidates. You can find this kind of exposition elsewhere, for example in [this paper of Dan Bernstein](https://cr.yp.to/papers/paretoviz-20190603.pdf) --- although I should mention that Dan often disagrees with certain "consensus" viewpoints within lattice cryptography.
The paper is still useful of course, but if I recall Dan in particular has slightly non-consensus views on:

- The underlying choice of ring for RLWE (in particular, the size of its Galois group)
- Particularities of the definition of security often used in lattice cryptography (the "core-SVP" count)
- Certain potential patent issues with various RLWE-type techniques

One can read more about these disagreements on the NIST pqc [google group](https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/g/pqc-forum), but I don't know of some short summary of them.

Comment: Sorry, but that book is not yet finished (and we are not quite sure when it will be).  I don't know why it's listed on some sites. In the mean-time, you could take a look at a shorter survey/tutorial that just talks about encryption and signatures here: http://tinyurl.com/latticesurvey

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to understand the NIST submissions, all of them are required to have a "design rationale" section in their specification documents. These often point to relevant papers as well. In addition, their presentations (see [this](https://csrc.nist.gov/Events/2018/First-PQC-Standardization-Conference) and [this](https://csrc.nist.gov/Events/2019/second-pqc-standardization-conference) and [this](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/events/conferences/oxford-post-quantum-cryptography-workshop)) are often helpful in explaining intuitively the underlying principles.

If your focus is lattices, I recommend having a look at [this series of workshops](https://simons.berkeley.edu/programs/lattices2020). There are many introductory talks, and since it was organized last spring, it is pretty much the state of the art.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the belated reply.

I've found that the Simons Institute seminar on "*Lattices: Algorithms, Complexity, and Cryptography Boot Camp*" was pretty good as a generic intro to lattice crypto. [Thomas mentioned something close to this, but I wanted to be more specific.] This event happened Jan. 21 – Jan. 24, 2020 (just a month or so before COVID-19 hit the U.S.), so the content is fairly current.

The talks' videos can be found at:
https://simons.berkeley.edu/workshops/schedule/10563

Cheers